# Does anyone know of a good Arduino library for the Linksprite CC3000?

Tags: wifi, arduino-uno

I bought this Linksprite CC3000 WiFi Shield for Arduino from Amazon:
[image: Linksprite CC3000]

The company website is http://www.linksprite.com/

The product page for it is http://linksprite.com/wiki/index.php5?title=CC3000_WiFi_Shield_for_Arduino

On the product page there is a link for the Library & Test code which I've downloaded and placed into the library folder of my Arduino version 1.0.3 (because I read that the CC3000 doesn't work with the latest version of Arduino).

The sample/test scripts state "This is an example for the Tinysine CC3000 Wifi Shield" and when I attempt to run them I either get the error "Wifi shield not present" or it attempts to connect to my network and eventually times out over and over.

I've searched everywhere to try and find code that will work for this shield and I'm worried that I made a bad purchase.

Has anyone had experience with this shield or knowledge of how I can get it to work?

***EDIT 11/13/2015*** - 
I've been told through Amazon that the Tinysine code does work for this shield but I have yet to get it to work properly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found that the Adafruit CC3000 library works perfectly for this shield.

https://learn.adafruit.com/adafruit-cc3000-wifi/cc3000-library-software